# How to animate Constraints with Python?

Tags: python, animation, constraints, keyframes

I have a cube

```
cube = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
```

The cube has a constraint, follow path. I would like to animate the offset in this constraint. I **do** know how to edit the value of it, but i need to put in a keyframe. Is there something like:

```
cube.keyframe_insert(data_path='offset_constraint', frame=10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the property and select copy data path and use it :

in this case it's `constraints["Follow Path"].offset`

and the adding a keyframe would be like :

```
cube.keyframe_insert(data_path='constraints["Follow Path"].offset', frame=10)
```

[image]